# tar a folder given a path and store it inside another folder

Tags: tar

I'm trying to finish a little bash project and I got stuck while trying to tar a folder given a path. For example, the program receives the route `/home/folderx`. Then, it looks for every folder inside that directory with a `for i in ~/folderx/*; do...` loop. And here's the problem: I'm trying to tar every folder inside that route with `tar -czvf $i.tgz $i -P`, but it compress the entire route that was given to the program. At the end, I obtain a `.tgz` with the correct name (the name of the directory that I wanted to tar) but inside it there's `/home/folderx/name_of_the_folder/contents` instead of just `name_of_the_folder` contents.

What's the problem? Thank you very much.

Comment: > Then, it looks for every folder inside that directory with a `for i in ~/folderx/*; do...` :  

If they exist, that will also match other types of files.

To match only directories (excluding hidden directories, whose name begins with a `.`): `for i in ~/folderx/*/; do...`. 
Note the trailing slash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to be in the directory which you need to do tar.

In `for i in ~/folderx/*; do...`loop do

```
cd $i
tar -czvf $i.tgz . -P
cd -
```

This works for me.

Comment: That worked more or less for me. If I use your code, the script creates a folder with the correct name but, when decompressing, it leaves all content inside the directory. I finally used: 

`cd ~/directory_that_contents_the_folders_to_compress
final_name=$(basename $i)"_"$(date +"%Y%m%d").tgz
tar -czf $final_name $(basename $i) -P && mv $final_name /detination_folder
cd -`

Answer (score 0):

Create the archive file first and then run the command.

For example:

`destination__folder = "name_of_folder.tgz"`

`tar czvf $path/to/destination_folder $i`

In the above example `$i` is the one that you are already using in your script.